# How can I update LOGIN and EXTERNAL_AUTH_ID in Bitrix with an API call?

Tags: bitrix

In Bitrix how can I update the fields `b_user.Login` and `b_user.EXTERNAL_AUTH_ID` (login type) with an API call?
I guess I should use the method `user.update`, but how do I have to reference this fields?
Is it even possible to do this with the API?

Answer (score 1):

You can't update `LOGIN` or `EXTERNAL_AUTH_ID` user filds by using standard `user.update` endpoint.

If you have Bitrix24 On-Premise Edition, you can create new endpoint, like `local.user.update` and use `CUser::Update(id,fields)` method. For this you need to subscribe **OnRestServiceBuildDescription** event and pass method name, that returns description about endpoint handler.

Here is [ref](https://dev.1c-bitrix.ru/learning/course/?COURSE_ID=99&LESSON_ID=7985&LESSON_PATH=8771.5380.7985) to docs